# Input dimension for CrossEntropy Loss in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, loss, index-error

For a binary classification problem with `batch_size = 1`, I have logit and label values using which I need to calculate loss.

```
logit: tensor([0.1198, 0.1911], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
label: tensor(1], device='cuda:0')
# calculate loss
loss_criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss_criterion.cuda()
loss = loss_criterion( b_logits, b_labels )
```

However, this always results in the following error,

```
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

What input dimensions is the CrossEntropyLoss actually asking for?

Comment: I think you are missing a dimension, the batch dimension. Compare `[0, 1]`, which doesn't have a batch size, and `[[0, 1]]`, which has a batch size of 1.

Comment: @amdex Yes, this worked. Adding the batch dimension using b_logits.unsqueeze(0). Could you maybe write this as an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing wrong shape of tensors.
`shape` should be ([from doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss))

> - Input: *`(N,C)`* where `C` = number of classes
> - Target: `(N)` where each value is `0 ≤ targets[i] ≤ C−1`

So here, `b_logits` shape should be `([1,2])` instead of `([2])` to make it right shape you can use [`torch.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) like `b_logits.view(1,-1)`.

And `b_labels` shape should be `([1])`.
Ex.:

```py
b_logits = torch.tensor([0.1198, 0.1911], requires_grad=True)
b_labels = torch.tensor([1])
loss_criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

loss = loss_criterion( b_logits.view(1,-1), b_labels )
loss
tensor(0.6581, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```